# similarity between two sentences

Tags: similarities, measurement, natural-language, metric

I have run an experiment where users were given a distorted sentence and asked to restore it. Currently, I am interested to grade the results on the scale between 0 to 1. I'm wondering if there any well-known ways to do so?

I am not interested in the "semantic quality" but only in the word for word similarity.

Answer (score 1):

There is the BLEU score (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLEU ) used in machine translation that might fit your intentions.

For a more detailed discussion of the BLEU score see this stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390397/bleu-score-implementation-for-sentence-similarity-detection

Comment: From the WikiPedia article: "BLEU is designed to approximate human judgement at a corpus level, and performs badly if used to evaluate the quality of individual sentences."

Comment: @fnl I thought it might be applicable because the OP states "I am not interested in the "semantic quality" but only in the word for word similarity."

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions for this kind of problem. Have you tried for instance the Levenshtein distance, jaccard index overlap coefficient, or any other string distance method? [Wikipedia link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric)

Keep in mind that your sentences should be tokenized into words before applying these methods...